# Clicking on file download links served by Django works in Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: django

If I click on a file download link in Chrome, the file gets downloaded as expected.  If I click on it in Firefox, nothing happens.  However, if I right click on the link and select "Open in New Tab", then the download proceeds as normal.  I'm not sure why left clicking the link directly won't download the file in Firefox.  Could this be related to my `Content-Disposition` header?

Relevant code snippet...

```
    file_location = '/downloads/' + directoryName + '/' + installerVersion + '.' + extension

    try:
        data = open(file_location, 'r').read()
    except IOError:
        return redirect('/error/')

    response = HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/x-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=' + installerVersion + '.' + extension
    return resp
```

Comment: I think its not a problem related to django. It probably is related to JS/html(button/link etc) on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as [ruddra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696165/ruddra) alluded to above, this was related to the fact that the page in question is being loaded through a sandboxed `iframe.`

Adding the `allow-popups`value to the `sandbox` attribute fixed the issue in Firefox.  Oddly the issue never existed with Chrome or IE, but I assume that is related to how those browsers handle iframes.